# Click/tap delay for web app on tablets

Tags: javascript, mobile

I made a simple little "wack-a-mole"-style game for my kids with JavaScript and HTML, and it performs exactly as it should on a PC.  As soon as you tap the animal (penguin, in this case) it shows as being wacked.  I'm using a `window.setTimeout` to try to time the images.

However, on tablets (tried on an iPad and an iPad Mini 2) there is a delay when tapping, so it isn't always counted correctly.  I've tried it on a Windows 10 PC with touch screen and it functions as expected, but on the iPads it always has a small delay, but enough to throw off the gameplay.

Is there any way to account for this delay on mobile devices?  I hesitate to change the timing of all of the images (the penguin poking its head up, then coming all the way up, then going back into its hole) because it works just like it should on Windows PCs.

I tested it in both Chrome and Safari on the iPad and iPad Mini 2, with the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Detect the devices and use `touchstart`, `touchend` events rather than `click`. Delay is around _300ms_ Refer this: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/

Comment: There are also JS libraries that can help: http://benhowdle.im/touche/, https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: @RayonDabre I added `touchend` events like you suggested and it worked perfectly.  That sitepoint.com article is very informative.  Thanks!